# Unstable MySQL st_distance_sphere results

Tags: mysql, sql

Results given from MySQL when using `st_distance_sphere` seem really unstable.

Running this query on a users table:
(list of users within 9.45 km from point)

`` select *, st_distance_sphere(`location`, ST_GeomFromText('point(-74.0104915 45.5576996)')) as distance from `users` having `distance` < 9450 ``

returns the correct results.

but removing 1 meter from the radius in the query:

`` select *, st_distance_sphere(`location`, ST_GeomFromText('point(-74.0104915 45.5576996)')) as distance from `users` having `distance` < 9449 ``

gives me this SQL syntax error: `#1210 - Incorrect arguments to st_distance_sphere`

I also noticed adding a `limit` statement changes the point at which the query breaks, depending on the limit number.

Has someone had similar experiences with this type of query? I'm having trouble figuring out what's going on here.

I'm using MySQL 5.7

Thank you!

**Edit:** 
Further testing shows that the query works fine on small sets (<~2-3k rows) but starts to break above that, very strange.

Comment: Removing 1 meter isn't the only change shown in your examples. The 2 examples use different tables. Is there a `location` column in `members`?

Comment: Hi, that was a mistake in the question, the actual error occurs on the same table. Edited out, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After tons of testing, I finally found the origin of the instability:

A single user had an **invalid latitude/longitude coordinate in the database** (-100, 100), probably because of some human intervention through phpmyadmin.

Latitude should be between -90.0 and 90.0,
and longitude between -180.0 to 180.0

When that user ended up within the radius of one of our searches, the query crashed. This is why all the parameters had an impact on the error (limit statement, radius range and center point). As soon as the user entered the result the thing went bonkers.

Lesson learned, protect your data!